xsane display text font too small
i don't even know if it's possible but i'm gonna ask anyway. I'm running kubuntu 24.04 and xsane. It scans and works perfectly but my issue is the text on the menu bar and buttons is too small. Is it possible to enlarge it or should I just use a different app?
